# Haskell-Stack failing to build project with DateTime dependency despite entry in stack.yaml

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, build-error

So I'm trying to add this package: [datetime-0.3.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/datetime-0.3.1) and I added what I *think* is the correct reference in the stack.yaml file. I tried using stack solver but that doesn't seem exist anymore. I also looked for some equivalent of pip so I could just do *stack install datetime-0.3.1* or something similar but that doesn't appear to be something stack does.

The code:

```
module FhirDataTypes (
    FhirId (..),
    toFhirId
) where

import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Data.List (length)
import Coding as Coding
import Data.Decimal
import FhirUri (FhirUri(..))
import FhirString (FhirString(..))
import SimpleQuantity (SimpleQuantity(..))
import Data.DateTime

newtype FhirId = FhirId FhirString deriving (Show)

toFhirId :: FhirString -> Maybe FhirId
toFhirId fs@(FhirString s)
    | length s > 64 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ FhirId fs

data Money = Money  { value :: Decimal
                    , currency :: Code
}

data Range = Range  {   low :: SimpleQuantity
                    ,   high :: SimpleQuantity
}

data Ratio = Ratio  {   numerator :: Quantity
                    ,   denominator :: Quantity
}

data Period = Period    { start :: DateTime
                        , end :: DateTime
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
PS C:\util\haskell\fhir-practice> stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for fhir-practice-0.1.0.0:
DateTime needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version (no package with that name found, perhaps there is a typo in
         a package's build-depends or an omission from the stack.yaml packages list?) needed since fhir-practice is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:


Plan construction failed.
```

My stack.yaml file:

```
flags: {}
packages:
- .
extra-deps: 
- network-  uri-2.6.1.0@sha256:62cc45c66023e37ef921d5fb546aca56a9c786615e05925fb193a70bf0913690
- Decimal-0.4.2
- datetime-0.3.1
resolver: lts-13.24
```

Comment: (1) `stack install` is mostly used for installing binaries globally, not for project-specific packages. (2) Do you have a `.cabal` file or a `package.yaml` file? Does it spell out `datetime` under `dependencies`? Note the all lowercase spelling. It is unclear why stack thinks `DateTime` is the appropriate casing. (3) Are you sure you want `datetime` instead of [`time`](https://www.stackage.org/package/time)? The latter is still being maintained, whereas the [last upload](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/datetime) for `datetime` was 4 years back.

Comment: If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll gladly mark it as such. Using UTCTime instead of DateTime and adding the reference in stack.yaml (time-1.8.0.2@sha256:e71437d137e609599afd09f70d50a4d20a123610d303d03ab094440a5a77cc6b,5409) solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `stack install` is mostly used for installing binaries globally, not for project-specific packages.
2. You probably want to use the `time` package, not `datetime`. as the former is actively maintained. Moreover, in your case, [time](https://www.stackage.org/package/time/snapshots) is present in LTS-13.24, so you shouldn't need to add it to extra-deps. The extra-deps field is only for dependencies (including transitive ones) which are not present in your resolver.